# Display jQuery UI dialog multiple windows dynamically clicking buttons

Tags: jquery

I'm just new to jQuery and UI. Please give me advice about code below. I want to display jquery dialog windows on the same page by clicking buttons.  Need your help.Thanks, Shaw.

**HTML**:

```
<button id="opener_1">Enlarge</button>
<div id="dialog_1" title="Dialog Title">Enlarge
  <img class="large_1" src="./large1.jpg" style="display:none" />
</div>

 <button id="opener_2">Enlarge</button>
 <div id="dialog_2" title="Dialog Title">Enlarge
  <img class="large_2" src="./large2.jpg" style="display:none" />
</div>

<button id="opener_3">Enlarge</button>
<div id="dialog_3" title="Dialog Title">Enlarge
  <img class="large_3" src="./large3.jpg" style="display:none" />
</div>

 <button id="opener_1">Enlarge</button>
 <div id="dialog_1" title="Dialog Title">Enlarge
  <img class="large_1" src="./large1.jpg" style="display:none" />
  </div>

 <button id="opener_1">Enlarge</button>
 <div id="dialog_1" title="Dialog Title">Enlarge
  <img class="large_1" src="./large2.jpg" style="display:none" />
</div>

<button id="opener_1">Enlarge</button>
<div id="dialog_1" title="Dialog Title">Enlarge
  <img class="large_1" src="./large3.jpg" style="display:none" />
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i <= button.length; i++) {
        $(function () {
            $('#dialog_' + [i]).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: false,
                width: "auto",
                height: "auto"
            })
        });
        $(function(){
            $('#opener_' + [i]).click(function () {
                $('.large_' + [i]).dialog('open');
            });
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, the ID attribute must be unique.

Given the following HTML

```
<button id="opener_1">Enlarge</button>
<div class="dialog" title="Dialog Title">Enlarge 1
  <img class="large_1" src="./large1.jpg" style="display:none" />
</div>

 <button id="opener_2">Enlarge</button>
 <div class="dialog" title="Dialog Title">Enlarge 2
  <img class="large_2" src="./large2.jpg" style="display:none" />
</div>

 <button id="opener_3">Enlarge</button>
 <div class="dialog" title="Dialog Title">Enlarge 3
  <img class="large_3" src="./large3.jpg" style="display:none" />
</div>
```

You can use this Javascript

```
$(function(){
    $('.dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: false,
        width: "auto",
        height: "auto"
   });

    $('button').each(function(i) {
        var el = $(this);
        el.click(function () {
            $('.dialog').dialog('close'); // Close all open dialogues
            $('.dialog').eq(i).dialog('open'); // Open relevant dialogue
        });
    });
});
```

Working example http://fiddle.jshell.net/q2cU2/1/

Comment: Thank you so much! it's perfect. I try to modify my project using your advice. Thanks.

Comment: Kyra, thanks and can I ask your favor more? My site pages have thubnails and each thumnails below has 3 kinds of button to 1)display enlarge image of thumbnail, 2)display related text, 3)display related PDF file. Its HTML is in jsFiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/excellency/LYh8U/   Hope your advice again. Thanks.

Comment: That JS should work as long as the number of buttons equals the number of dialogues. Have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/LYh8U/2/

Comment: Remember to use unique ID attributes on your HTML elements and to check the syntax of your HTML code, you forgot to add the closing `"` in your `iframe` `class` attribute